# How do we put an image for a website Tab?

Tags: html, image, tabs

I am creating a website and I don't know how to put an image on the tab, like here:

[image: example]

what HTML code is required to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats a so called "favicon", you can add it by adding this in the HTML-Head-Element:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
```

where `favicon.png` is a file on your server.

---

You can also do it without a file with `href="data:image/x-icon;base64,......"` where you plase a base64 encoded image string in there. (For example with this tool: https://www.base64-image.de)

Comment: so when I upload the website, do I upload it to the server at the same time?

Comment: Yes, just place the icon in the root folder of your webiste, or whereever the link `href="/favicon.png"` is pointing to

Comment: @FlipFloop did it work for you? Do you need any more help?